# How to take bytes as input without any manipulation in it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, bit

I am taking a byte as input
b'\xe2I4\xdd\r\xe5\xfcy^4\xd5'

but it gets converted into string.

so when i am to trying to convert this string to byte it is again manipulating it and giving me output as:

```
b"b'\\xe2I4\\xdd\\r\\xe5\\xfcy^4\\xd5'"
```

My desired output is that when i provide **b'\xe2I4\xdd\r\xe5\xfcy^4\xd5'** it convert it into byte as it is without manipulating it or adding any character or symbol.

Any resource or reference will be helpful.

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The BAD idea

You could pass the value of `input()` to `eval()` function. The function `eval()` directly evaluates a string as if it were directly executed in Python. Although it might feel like a best feature at first but due to the same reason it is pretty much **unsafe** to use it within any production-level application, since, the user can execute any code using that which might cause a lot of problems.

#### Better alternative

You can use a safer alternative to `eval()` which is `ast.literal_eval()`. This function evaluates a given string as Python literals *(like string, numbers, bytes object, etc.)*. In case if a string does not contain any literal *(like function calls, object creation, assignment, etc.)*, this function throws an error. Enough about that let's see how you could get this working.

```
import ast

user_input = input()
eval_expr = ast.literal_eval(user_input)
```

If you want to check if the input is a `bytes` literal, you could use the `isinstance` function to check and then perform required action.

```
# Optional: Handle if `eval_expr` is not a `bytes` literal
if not isinstance(eval_expr, bytes):
    ...
```

So, all you need to do is import the module `ast` first. Then take the user's input. Thereafter pass this input string to `ast.literal_eval()` function to evaluate the string.

Comment: Thanks but it helped me to much extent.